# How to count number of lines (Hough Trasnform) in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, line, hough-transform

I am successfully able to detect hair strands in an image as lines. I see that the output image detects each hair as line. I use `cvHoughLines2()` with method parameter as `CV_HOUGH_PROBABILISTIC`.

Now I want to count these lines. The output image shows 1 or 2 line over each hair. I see that each line is composed of small line segments. And  so it is difficult to directly get their total number.
Any suggestions on this?

Thanks,
Pradeep

Comment: Have you able to count hair line ? @pradeep

Answer (score 0):

You may actually be better off using the Canny edge detector. From your description, it seems to have a few key advantages over the Hough transform:

- responds to contours of arbitrary shape, not just straight lines;
- performs noise reduction and non-maximum suppression to minimize the response; and
- does a second detection with looser threshold to "trace" or "solidify" edges.

Given the right parameters, it may be able to uniquely detect each hair with a single, continuous line.

This is implemented in OpenCV in the `cvCanny()` function. Play around with the value of the `threshold1` and `threshold2` parameters (3rd and 4th arguments) to experiment with detection and tracing.

As for actually counting the lines, I'm not sure how best to approach this (Canny output is a somewhat different form from Hough transform output), but you might find it easier to work with unique, solid edges than with fragmented sets of line parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The hough function should return a vector in OpenCV2 or a CvSeq in OpenCV1. You can easily get their length and iterate through them. See the sample code in the OpenCV documentation for more details.