# Opencv - How to get number of vertical lines present in image (count of lines)

Tags: c++, swift, objective-c, opencv, image-processing

Firstly I integrate OpenCV framework to XCode and All the OpenCV code is on ObjectiveC and I am using in Swift Using bridging header. I am new to OpenCV Framework and trying to achieve count of vertical lines from the image.

Here is my code:
First I am converting the image to GrayScale

```
 + (UIImage *)convertToGrayscale:(UIImage *)image {
    cv::Mat mat;
    UIImageToMat(image, mat);
    cv::Mat gray;
    cv::cvtColor(mat, gray, CV_RGB2GRAY);
    UIImage *grayscale = MatToUIImage(gray);
    return grayscale;
}
```

Then, I am detecting  edges so I can find the line of gray color

```
+ (UIImage *)detectEdgesInRGBImage:(UIImage *)image {
    cv::Mat mat;
    UIImageToMat(image, mat);
    
    //Prepare the image for findContours
    cv::threshold(mat, mat, 128, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);

    //Find the contours. Use the contourOutput Mat so the original image doesn't get overwritten
    std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
    cv::Mat contourOutput = mat.clone();
    cv::findContours( contourOutput, contours, CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE );

    NSLog(@"Count =>%lu", contours.size());
    
    //For Blue
    /*cv::GaussianBlur(mat, gray, cv::Size(11, 11), 0); */
    
    UIImage *grayscale = MatToUIImage(mat);
    return grayscale;
}
```

This both Function is written on Objective C

Here, I am calling both function Swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let img = UIImage(named: "imagenamed")
        let img1 = Wrapper.convert(toGrayscale: img)
        self.capturedImageView.image = Wrapper.detectEdges(inRGBImage: img1)
    }
```

I was doing this for some days and finding some useful documents(Reference Link)

[OpenCV - how to count objects in photo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34478402/opencv-how-to-count-objects-in-photo)

[How to count number of lines (Hough Trasnform) in OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2026229/how-to-count-number-of-lines-hough-trasnform-in-opencv)

OPENCV Documents

https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?#findcontours

Basically, I understand the first we need to convert this image to black and white, and then using `cvtColor, threshold and findContours` we can find the colors or lines.

I am attaching the image that vertical Lines I want to get.

Original Image

[image: Original Image]

Output Image that I am getting

[image: Output Image that I am getting]

**I got number of lines count =>10**
**I am not able to get accurate count here.**

Please guide me on this. Thank You!

Comment: I guess your line counter counts the branches as two or more lines?

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to detect the number of the vertical lines, there is a very simple approach I can suggest for you. You already got a clear output and I used this output in my code. Here are the steps before the code:

1. **Preprocess** the input image to get the lines clearly
2. Check each row and check until get a pixel whose value is higher than 100(**threshold value** I chose)
3. Then increase the **line counter** for that row
4. Continue on that line until get a pixel whose value is lower than 100
5. Restart from step 3 and finish the image for each row
6. At the end, check the **most repeated element** in the array which you assigned line numbers for each row. This number will be the number of vertical lines.

Note: If the steps are difficult to understand, think like this way:

> " I am checking the first row, I found a pixel which is higher than
> 100, now this is a line edge starting, increase the counter for this
> row. Search on this row until get a pixel smaller than 100, and then
> research a pixel bigger than 100. when row is finished, assign the
> line number for this row to a big array. Do this for all image. At the
> end, since some lines looks like two lines at the top and also some
> noises can occur, you should take the most repeated element in the big
> array as the number of lines."

Here is the code part in C++:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>


int main()
{
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("/ur/img/dir/img.jpg",cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    std::vector<int> numberOfVerticalLinesForEachRow;


    cv::Rect r(0,0,img.cols-10,200);

    img = img(r);

    bool blackCheck = 1;

    for(int i=0; i<img.rows; i++)
    {
        int numberOfLines = 0;

        for(int j=0; j<img.cols; j++)
        {
            if((int)img.at<uchar>(cv::Point(j,i))>100 && blackCheck)
            {
                numberOfLines++;
                blackCheck = 0;
            }
            if((int)img.at<uchar>(cv::Point(j,i))<100)
                blackCheck = 1;
        }

        numberOfVerticalLinesForEachRow.push_back(numberOfLines);
    }

    // In this part you need a simple algorithm to check the most repeated element
    for(int k:numberOfVerticalLinesForEachRow)
        std::cout<<k<<std::endl;





    cv::namedWindow("WinWin",0);

    cv::imshow("WinWin",img);

    cv::waitKey(0);


}
```

Comment: I used your code I found a big array but the number that I am looking for that not contain in the array, and also numberOfLines is always showing me zero. Could you please help me on this?. Thank You!

Comment: Did you use the image you got as output. Which is 2nd image you shared? I used 2nd image you shared as input in my code and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Here's another possible approach. It relies mainly on the [cv::thinning](https://docs.opencv.org/master/df/d2d/group__ximgproc.html#ga37002c6ca80c978edb6ead5d6b39740c) function from the *extended image processing module* to reduce the lines at a width of `1` pixel. We can crop a `ROI` from this image and count the number of transitions from `255` (white) to `0` (black). These are the steps:

1. **Threshold** the image using Otsu's method
2. Apply some **morphology** to clean up the binary image
3. Get the **skeleton** of the image
4. **Crop** a `ROI` from the center of the image
5. **Count** the number of *jumps* from `255` to `0`

This is the code, be sure to include the extended image processing module (**ximgproc**) and also link it before compiling it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/ximgproc.hpp> // The extended image processing module

// Read Image:
std::string imagePath = "D://opencvImages//";
cv::Mat inputImage = cv::imread( imagePath+"IN2Xh.png" );

// Convert BGR to Grayscale:
cv::cvtColor( inputImage, inputImage, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY );

// Get binary image via Otsu:
cv::threshold( inputImage, inputImage, 0, 255, cv::THRESH_OTSU );
```

The above snippet produces the following image:

[image]

Note that there's a little bit of noise due to the thresholding, let's try to remove those isolated blobs of white pixels by applying some *morphology*. Maybe an `opening`, which is an `erosion` followed by `dilation`. The structuring elements and iterations, though, are not the same, and these where found by experimentation. I wanted to remove the majority of the isolated blobs without modifying too much the original image:

```
// Apply Morphology. Erosion + Dilation:
// Set rectangular structuring element of size 3 x 3:
cv::Mat SE = cv::getStructuringElement( cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(3, 3) );
// Set the iterations:
int morphoIterations = 1;
cv::morphologyEx( inputImage, inputImage, cv::MORPH_ERODE, SE, cv::Point(-1,-1), morphoIterations);

// Set rectangular structuring element of size 5 x 5:
SE = cv::getStructuringElement( cv::MORPH_RECT, cv::Size(5, 5) );
// Set the iterations:
morphoIterations = 2;
cv::morphologyEx( inputImage, inputImage, cv::MORPH_DILATE, SE, cv::Point(-1,-1), morphoIterations);
```

This combination of structuring elements and iterations yield the following filtered image:

[image]

Its looking alright. Now comes the main idea of the algorithm. If we compute the skeleton of this image, we would "normalize" all the lines to a width of 1 pixel, which is very handy, because we could reduce the image to a `1 x 1` (row) matrix and count the number of jumps. Since the lines are "normalized" we could get rid of possible overlaps between lines. Now, *skeletonized* images sometimes produce artifacts near the borders of the image. These artifacts resemble *thickened anchors* at the first and last row of the image. To prevent these artifacts we can extend borders prior to computing the skeleton:

```
// Extend borders to avoid skeleton artifacts, extend 5 pixels in all directions:
cv::copyMakeBorder( inputImage, inputImage, 5, 5, 5, 5, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, 0 );

// Get the skeleton:
cv::Mat imageSkelton;
cv::ximgproc::thinning( inputImage, imageSkelton );
```

This is the skeleton obtained:

[image]

Nice. Before we count jumps, though, we must observe that the lines are *skewed*. If we reduce this image directly to a one row, some overlapping could indeed happen between to lines that are too skewed. To prevent this, I crop a middle section of the skeleton image and count transitions there. Let's crop the image:

```
// Crop middle ROI:
cv::Rect linesRoi;
linesRoi.x = 0;
linesRoi.y = 0.5 * imageSkelton.rows;
linesRoi.width = imageSkelton.cols;
linesRoi.height = 1;

cv::Mat imageROI = imageSkelton( linesRoi );
```

This would be the new `ROI`, which is just the middle row of the skeleton image:

[image]

Let me prepare a `BGR` copy of this just to draw some results:

```
// BGR version of the Grayscale ROI:
cv::Mat colorROI;
cv::cvtColor( imageROI, colorROI, cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR );
```

Ok, let's loop through the image and count the transitions between `255` and `0`. That happens when we look at the value of the current pixel and compare it with the value obtained an iteration earlier. The current pixel must be `0` and the past pixel `255`. There's more than a way to loop through a `cv::Mat` in `C++`. I prefer to use `cv::MatIterator_`s and pointer arithmetic:

```
// Set the loop variables:
cv::MatIterator_<cv::Vec3b> it, end;
uchar pastPixel = 0;
int jumpsCounter = 0;
int i = 0; 

// Loop thru image ROI and count 255-0 jumps:
for (it = imageROI.begin<cv::Vec3b>(), end = imageROI.end<cv::Vec3b>(); it != end; ++it) {

    // Get current pixel
    uchar &currentPixel = (*it)[0];
    // Compare it with past pixel:
    if ( (currentPixel == 0) && (pastPixel == 255) ){
        // We have a jump:
        jumpsCounter++;
        // Draw the point on the BGR version of the image:
        cv::line( colorROI, cv::Point(i, 0), cv::Point(i, 0), cv::Scalar(0, 0, 255), 1 );
    }

    // current pixel is now past pixel:
    pastPixel = currentPixel;
    i++;

}

// Show image and print number of jumps found:
cv::namedWindow( "Jumps Found", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL );
cv::imshow( "Jumps Found", colorROI );
cv::waitKey( 0 );

std::cout<<"Jumps Found: "<<jumpsCounter<<std::endl;
```

The points where the jumps were found are drawn in red, and the number of total jumps printed is:

[image]

```
Jumps Found: 9
```